# How to make this prime number finding program in Python more useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this program in Python 3 to check whether a number is prime or not.

The program is as follows-

```
  #Python program to check if the input number is prime or not

  # take input from the user
  num = int(input("Enter a number: "))


  if num > 1:
     # check for factors
     for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
        else:
           print(num,"is a prime number")
        else:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Now,My problem is that I cannot input exponential numbers in this program.(I mean numbers in the form 2**4 or 5*8).

If I input 2**4 I get this output-

[image]

How do I change my program to input exponents?

Comment: with this indentation I don't believe it even compiles. Also, hint: any number written as an exponential is surely not a prime!!

Comment: @apomene By exponential I mean a^b form....

Comment: exactly, such number is divided by a, so obviously is not a prime

Comment: @apomene Why do you think I will only write a^b...I will write (a^b)-c...I have that much basic knowledge about maths...

Comment: @apomene See my second comment before replying...

Comment: Your second `else` is wrongly indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = eval(input())
```

will do what you want (it's not safe but for a toy program it should be ok) but by definition, a number written like this is not a prime, so I don't really see the point.

You can also save a lot of iterations by using :

```
 for i in range(2,sqrt(num)+1):
```

Comment: What does eval stand for?

Comment: Basically, it considers that its string argument is python code, and so evaluate it, the same as when you enter code in the python interpreter. It's not safe because a malicious user can enter code that will be evaluated without you controlling it.

Comment: I am getting sqrt is not defined...syntax error...why?

Comment: from math import sqrt